# CSS position absolute inside td overflow hidden

Tags: css, overflow, hidden, absolute

I have a table (using kendoui grid datatable) that the td is `overflow: hidden`

I have a basic problem that my JS dropdown with its `position: absolute` inside it is truncated.

[image]

if I set overflow: hidden to overflow-y: auto I don't like the layout as well (it has vertical scrollbar).

[image]

so how do I have it z-index stacking relatively to the table row/cell?

Answer (score 2):

ok i found the answer. i need to reset all overflow from td up to the parents with `overflow: inherit`

Comment: I would go with `overflow: visible`. `inherit` just makes you rely on the value of the parent element which may be not the one you want.